# Rotation to rigid body objects

Tags: animation, physics, rigidbody

*I can't really find much about this and most of answers I do find are rather outdated.*

Is there any way to get rigid bodies to rotate by a force?

For example I would like the cubes in this "explosion" to also rotate.

[image]

Comment: So I solved it by making a sphere, made it a passive rigid object and animated it so it pushed the objects up up and away. It didn't solve the force question but I was in a hurry here so for a quick fix it worked.

Comment: Nice idea, maybe answer to yourslef in the Your Answer field?